# Fix a footer div cross mobile platforms - Jquery?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

Does anybody have a simple effective solution to fix a footer menu to the bottom of a viewport window?  Absolute positioning appears to work in all but Iphone.

I thought that their should be a simple jquery or jquery touch script out there to do this, but I'm yet to find one!

Any advice greatfully received!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, you can achieve this by adding a footer with fixed-positioning, see

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Just create a navbar within the footer for a menu, see

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

or alternatively

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html

Comment: See also the fullscreen positining.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work. it grafts in win/safari...

http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/stsfX/3/

good luck!

Comment: cant get that one to work on the iphone, cheers for your help though.  Paul